# Which is correct: congratulation or congratulations?

Tags: meaning, difference

I thinking about this two..?

when we use congratulation and where we use congratulations.?

Which is correct: congratulation or congratulations? where am i use ..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Congratulations** is what you say when you congratulate someone.

> A: I won the contest.
>
> B: Really, congratulations!

**Congratulation** is used when you are referring to an act of congratulating someone.

> He sent her a note of congratulation on her election victory.

([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/congratulation))